# WPF Lost-Focus issue in same control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, lost-focus

I have a small problem with focusing in .net/wpf. I have written a custom user control which contains a `TextBox` and a `SearchButton`. The user-control has a lost focus event, which validate the content of the textbox if the focus is leaving. But now I have the problem, if I click on my search button, the lost focus event of the user control gets fired, even if I click on the button in the custom user control. (The button additionally has the option `TabStop="False"`:

[image: Custom-User-Control design]

The problem is, that I don't want to fire the event if I click on the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
Focusable="False"
```

of your search button and the TextBox will not lose the focus because the button doesn't get the focus.

Comment: had the opposite problem, set it to true and it works :D thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can Do this Check in Event  like this

```
protected void LostFocusEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox.Text.Length>0)
    {
      // if there is any character in TextBox
    return;
    }

   // your validation Code goes here
}
```

Comment: But the textbox validation is independent from clicking the Button